# Spyder closes while training a neural network

Tags: python, neural-network, crash, spyder

I'm using Windows 10 with Spyder (Python 3.6). Everything seems fine, I leave my PC on for the training, but when I come back I find Spyder closed. I tried to uninstall and reinstall Tensorflow, updated everything, but it still happens. What should I do? I don't even get a crash message.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. When I tried to train for longer than 30 epochs, Spyder stopped responding after some time (you had to close it). In my case the problem was solved by decreasing the (runtime) output.